# SSIS 2005 - How to get the timestamp properties for a file

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

How do you get a timestamp from a file with SQL Server Intergration Services 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a script task, something along these lines should do the trick:

```
    Dim filePath As String = "C:\YourFolder\YourFile.ext"

    If File.Exists(filePath) = False Then
        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Failure
        Return
    End If

    Dim currentDate As Date = DateTime.Now
    Dim fileCreateDate As Date = File.GetCreationTime(path)

    If currentDate.ToShortDateString <> fileCreateDate.ToShortDateString Then
        'Do something
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the open-source [File Properties Task](http://filepropertiestask.codeplex.com/) to get and/or set any one of the three timestamps on a file.